# Vue.js : how to filter a table with a custom filter

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Table has two columns `Name`, `Age`. Searching works by name. As you type the name of user the table will trim down to the specific user name.

But I want it to be filtered by age using a comparison operator `<` or `>`.

[Code pen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PERgxa)

**Html**

```
<div id="demo" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input v-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Username to search">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <select class="form-control" v-model="searchOperator">
        <option value=">">></option>
        <option value="<"><</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <input v-model="searchName" class="form-control" placeholder="Age">
    </div>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-repeat="column: columns">
          <a href="#" v-on="click: sortBy(column)" v-class="active: sortKey == column">
            {{ column | capitalize }}
          </a>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr v-repeat="users | filterBy search | orderBy sortKey reverse">
        <td>{{ name }}</td>
        <td>{{ age }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Vue :**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',

  data: {
    sortKey: 'name',

    reverse: false,

    searchName: '',

    searchOperator: '',

    searchAge: '',

    columns: ['name', 'age'],

    newUser: {},

    users: [
      { name: 'John', age: 50 },
      { name: 'Jane', age: 22 },
      { name: 'Paul', age: 34 }
    ]
  },

  methods: {
    sortBy: function(sortKey) {
      this.reverse = (this.sortKey == sortKey) ? ! this.reverse : false;

      this.sortKey = sortKey;
    }
  }
});
```

What is the best approach to achieve this? I tried but nothing seem to be working.

Comment: So yeah mean that type name the select operator the age to find the record ?

Comment: Yes thats exactly i want !

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is : `v-repeat` is deprecated. So you should be using `v-for` instead.

```
<tr v-for="user in filteredPersons">
  <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.age }}</td>
</tr>
```

`filteredPersons` is the name of a computed function that returns an array :

```
computed: {
    filteredPersons: function () {
      return this.users
      .filter(this.filterByName)
      .filter(this.filterByAge)
      .sort(this.orderBy);
    }
  }
```

It filters and sorts the `users` array by combining two filter functions and one comparator function :

```
methods: {
    filterByName : function(user) {
      // no search, don't filter : 
      if (this.searchName.length === 0) {
        return true;
      }

      return  (user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchName.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    }, 
    filterByAge : function (user) {
      // no operator selected or no age typed, don't filter : 
      if (this.searchOperator.length === 0 || this.age.length === 0) {
        return true;
      }

      if (this.searchOperator === '>') {
        return (user.age > this.age); 
      } else  if (this.searchOperator === '<') {
        return (user.age < this.age);
      }      
    }, 
    orderBy : function (userA, userB) {
      let condition = (userA[this.sortKey] > userB[this.sortKey]);
      if (this.reverse) {
        return !condition;
      } else {
        return condition;
      }
    }
  },
```

Working snippet :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',

  data: {
    sortKey: 'name',
    reverse: false,
    searchName: '',
    searchOperator: '',
    searchAge: '',
    columns: ['name', 'age'],
    newUser: {},
    search: "",
    name: "",
    age: "",

    users: [
      { name: 'John', age: 50 },
      { name: 'Jane', age: 22 },
      { name: 'Paul', age: 34 },
      { name: 'Kate', age: 15 },
      { name: 'Amanda', age: 65 },
      { name: 'Steve', age: 38 },
      { name: 'Keith', age: 21 },
      { name: 'Don', age: 50 },
      { name: 'Susan', age: 21 }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy: function (sortKey) {
      this.reverse = (this.sortKey == sortKey) ? !this.reverse : false;

      this.sortKey = sortKey;
    }, 
    filterByName : function(user) {
      // no search, don't filter : 
      if (this.searchName.length === 0) {
        return true;
      }

      return  (user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchName.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    }, 
    filterByAge : function (user) {
      // no operator selected or no age typed, don't filter : 
      if (this.searchOperator.length === 0 || this.age.length === 0) {
        return true;
      }

      if (this.searchOperator === '>') {
        return (user.age > this.age); 
      } else  if (this.searchOperator === '<') {
        return (user.age < this.age);
      }      
    }, 
    orderBy : function (userA, userB) {
      let condition = (userA[this.sortKey] > userB[this.sortKey]);
      if (this.reverse) {
        return !condition;
      } else {
        return condition;
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredPersons: function () {
      return this.users
      .filter(this.filterByName)
      .filter(this.filterByAge)
      .sort(this.orderBy);
    }
  },  
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2em 0;
}

a {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: blue;
}

a.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/> 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="index.js" defer></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="demo" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input v-model="searchName" class="form-control" placeholder="Username to search">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <select class="form-control" v-model="searchOperator">
        <option value=">">></option>
        <option value="<"><</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <input v-model="age" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" type="number">
    </div>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="column in columns">
         <!-- <a href="#" v-on="click: sortBy(column)" >-->
         <!--  <a href="#"> -->
          <a href="#" v-on:click="sortBy(column)" v-bind:class="{active: sortKey == column}">
           
            <!--{{ column | capitalize }}-->
            {{column}}
          </a>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="user in filteredPersons">
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.age }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```